# Admob banner hide the last item of listview fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, admob, fragment

I have a fragment listview layout which is called in the activity_main layout ,the admob banner is placed at the bottom of activit_main layout , so when I scroll down until the last item of the listview I find him covered by the banner,here is the full activity_main layout :

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary_color"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/more_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/thumbsuo" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                style="@style/CategoryTab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL_contentProgressBarParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarParent"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"

            />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
            >

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/text_drawer_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/text_drawer_color"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is the full code of the listview_fragment :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    >

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/banner_layout"

        >

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/tan_background"
        android:divider="@color/tan_background"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

      />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

So I want that the listview is above the banner ,is there any solution for that ?Thanks in advance .

Comment: Check out ConstraintLayout's relative positioning: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#RelativePositioning

Answer (score 0):

You need to set alignment for it, your adview will always block everything at the bottom since you alignment towards parent bottom.

Wrap your list_view (which is inside view pager i assume) with constraint or relative layout (or even linear layout, it also works). Then align them as you want, align the view pager bottom on top of the adview and align the adview below the view pager.

Do something like this for the layout

```
<CoordinatorLayout..
    <LinearLayout..
        <ViewPager/>
        <AdView wrap content/>
    <LinearLayout/>
<CoordinatorLayout/>
```

Comment: yes  I know I have to place my view pager above the banner but the problem is that the coordinator layout bolcks me of doing that

Comment: you need to put another layout for that, coordinator doesn't support layout alignment

Comment: yes but can't remove the coordinator layout cuz im using it for hiding the toolbar when scrolling down

Comment: I fully understand it, you don't need to remove the coordinator, you only need to add more layout inside to wrap them